# Radians or degrees?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

In problem 2 from this page:

http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/Problems/rate_change.html

The last couple steps including the equation:
$$\frac{da}{dt} = \left[-\frac{\sin 2(25^\circ)}{5000~\text{m}}\right] \cdot \left[\frac{500 000~\text{m}}{3600~\text{s}}\right] = -0.005 \frac{\text{radians}}{\text{s}}$$

What here indicates that the output is rad/sec?  Obviously the angle is changing in some unit with respect to time, but how do we know it's radians?

Comment: Please use LaTeX for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Radian is not an unit, while degree is somehow.

Radian is actually the length of the arc, so it is a length ratio, while degree is radian you converted a bit in order to be able to divide it by 9, 3, 6, etc..

When you divide two lengths, you can't possibly get a result in degrees, it will always be in radians, and that is because degree need a conversion.

Some people think that it is simpler to use, and that is actually why it is used, but whenever you do a calculation, the result will be in radians (trigonometric invert function return radians, dividing two length return radians etc..)

Comment: How is a radian the length of an arc? Isn't one radian the angle for which the length of the arc corresponding the the angle is equal to the radius?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu The circumference of a unit circle (i.e. circle of radius = 1) is $2\pi.$  Therefore, equating $360^{\circ}$ with $2\pi$ radians means that as you traverse $2\pi$ radians around the unit circle, you have traversed exactly 1 circumference = $2\pi.$

Comment: @user2661923 What I meant was : Radian is a unit that measures angles, not lengths!

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu You have touched on a great source of confusion among 1st year Calculus students.  Technically, yes, your interpretation of radian is accurate.  However, consider (for example) the basis of saying that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2 +1}dx \;=\;$ arctan$(1) = \pi/4.$  If I have interpreted correctly "Calculus 2nd Ed." by Apostol, this result is based on the idea that $2\pi$ radians represents the circumference of the unit circle, rather than 360 degrees.  **I could be mistaken** however, it might be me who is confused.

Comment: @user2661923 I'm sorry, I couldn't quite understand your comment completely. I haven't properly started with calculus yet. I only did basic differentiation and integration from 3Blue1Browns's "Essence of Calculus" and using limits to define derivatives and integrals. That's all...

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu This clarification of what a radian signifies and how this significance provides a foundation for resolving certain Calculus problems is a topic that (in my opinion) can not be readily resolved on mathSE.  Instead it takes finding the **right** book and studying it, or (better still) several hours over a (for example) few weeks in one-on-one discussion with a teacher.  As a simple example where the distinction is significant, consider that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}dx =$ arctan$(1) = \pi/4,$ a **dimensionless number**, rather than $\pi/4$ *radians* (a purported angle).